# Benefit of Support library

Tags: android, version, compatibility, android-support-library

The benefits of the support libraries are the fact
that I can run later released feature like Material Design things
on a older version of android.

So why is it not possible to change the comileSdk to e.g. 22 
and the support libraries to the newest version?

My Gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion '23.0.1'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.stack.overflow"
        minSdkVersion 22
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    sourceSets {
        main { res.srcDirs = ['src/main/res', 'src/main/res/drawable/ic_action_search.png'] }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')

    //Google Libraries
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.0.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.0.+'

}
```

Android studio always marks the google libraries red and does not compile.

So why is it not possible to use the latest support libraries with a previous sdk?

Comment: if you update the version of the support library you need to update your sdk version number to match it

Comment: well I agree. But then there is no profit for compatibility for low sdk devices when I have to update the sdk version number to match it.

Comment: you are updating the targetSdkVersion not the minSdkVersion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please update your `targetSdkVersion 23`

Finally

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.0" or '23.0.1'

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.stack.overflow"
    minSdkVersion 17 // Set Your Version
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
```

And you can set

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.0'
```